# Use A For Loop to Run Apps Script - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to repeat a piece of code with a For Loop every time it sees a blank cell in Column N.

I am trying the below code but cant figure out where I am going wrong

```
  function CopyCellBelow() {
  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(14,2, lastRow-1);
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();

for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
  if(rangeValues[j] === ""){
    sheet.getRange(j+14);// Column N
    
    sheet.getRange('N2').activate();
    sheet.getRange('N3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    sheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    sheet.getRange('N2').activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    sheet.getRange('N1').activate();
   
    
  }else if (rangeValues[j] === "if cell has data"){
    //do nothing    
   }}};
```

In the image below you can see the yellow cells have the expected result which is copying the cell directly below

The next 3 blanks cells should have a 4 placed in them

[image]

Comment: Please reread you explanation.  You words don't agree with your image.

Comment: You need to learn how to write code without using activate.  It's slow and awkward.

Comment: Hi Cooper - Image updated. Sorry I am learning how to code any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
const copyCellBelow = () => {

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //change sheet name if needed
const range = sheet.getRange(1, 14, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); //change range if needed
const data = range.getValues().map( (cell, i, val) => (cell[0]) ? cell : val[i 
+ 1])
range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: JPV it didnt seem to work. i have a spreadsheet for you to look at if you can.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QO33qTgW2twDCjduneacbC4APCGXjomHbCETbsIVPyQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't access that spreadsheet. Please fix permissions (set it to 'anyone with the link can edit').

Comment: You pasted the code in another function declaration. I fixed it. Can you try again now?